# Running a external command using strings loaded from a text file

Tags: vbscript, winrar

I am trying to automate the extraction of a bunch of compressed files (.ARJ) in different directories.

I am currently using 2 text files to store 2 bits of information:

1. the current location and name of the compressed files (ARJFileNames.txt)
   sample - D:_Work_Splunk_TestBed\Branch00\LOAN.ARJ
2. the target location for the files to be extracted to (ARJFileLocations.txt)
   sample - D:_Work_Splunk_TestBed\Branch00

I am trying to use the `WScript.Shell` command to run WinRAR to extract the files from their current location to a targeted location.

My problem is when I call the external command from the loop I can't seem to get the syntax right for attaching the strings that I am pulling from the text files in tandem with the actually call to WinRar and its switch/command.

Here is my current code:

```vb
'Declaring Constants
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 3
'Declaring Variables
Dim fso, strFilePath, strFileName, fFilePath, fFileName, objShell, WinRAR, strCMD, SevenZip, ARJ

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")    

'Open Text Files for use
Set strFilePath     = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\_Work\_Splunk\_TestBed\ARJFileLocations.txt", ForReading, TristateFalse)
Set strFileName = fso.OpenTextFile("D:\_Work\_Splunk\_TestBed\ARJFileNames.txt", ForReading, TristateFalse)


Do Until strFilePath.AtEndOfStream
  fFilePath = strFilePath.ReadLine  'Get the location of the ARJ file
  fFileName = strFileName.ReadLine  'Get the target location for ARJ file contents 
  'Storing the command as 1 string'
  strCMD = "winrar x -y " & " " & fFileName & " " & fFilePath
  'Running the command in CLI'
  objShell.Run strCMD 
Loop

'Cleaning Up
Set strFilePath = Nothing
Set strFileName = Nothing
Set objShl = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read Concatenation Operator (&)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx97884w(v=vs.84).aspx) reference.

The command line should appear ultimately as it would if you typed it at the command prompt (verify by `Wscript.Echo Command`):

```
Command = """" & WinRAR & "\WinRAR.exe"" X " & fDLocation & " " & fTLocation
'         ↑↑↑↑                        ↑↑
' results to
' "D:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" X ARJLocation TargetLocation
' ↑                                  ↑
```

Use following if `fDLocation` or `fTLocation` contain spaces

```
Command = """" & WinRAR & "\WinRAR.exe"" X """ & fDLocation & """ """ & fTLocation & """"
'                                           ↑↑                 ↑↑ ↑↑                 ↑↑↑↑
' results to
' "D:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" X "ARJ Location" "Target Location"
' ↑                                  ↑   ↑            ↑ ↑               ↑
```

Moreover, I'd consider running the script and `WinRAR.exe` program synchronously (cf. [Run Method (Windows Script Host)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx) article) as follows:

```
Dim intRunResult
Do Until strARJLocations.AtEndOfStream
  fDLocation = strARJLocations.ReadLine     'Get the location of the ARJ file'
  fTLocation = strTargetLocation.ReadLine   'Get the target location for ARJ file contents'
  Command = """" & WinRAR & "\WinRAR.exe"" X """ & fDLocation & """ """ & fTLocation & """"
  intRunResult = objShell.Run ( Command, 1, True)
Loop
```